# Token does not renew automatically Angular and ADAL.js

Tags: javascript, angular, adal.js

We are currently implemented ADAL.js using Angular, but unfortunately the token does not renew automatically, the code is the following to handle the logic to renew the token

We added some logic to check if the token is expired and renew it automatically, but this is not working for me. The application kick you out to white page, and it is required to refresh the browser in order sign in again.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  checkAuthInterval$: Observable<number>;
  constructor(
    private jwtHelperService: JwtHelperService,
    private adal: MsAdalAngular6Service
  ) {
    this.checkAuthInterval$ = interval(6000).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.updateSession();
      })
    );
    this.checkAuthInterval$.subscribe();
  }

  public isAuthorized(allowedRoles: string[]): boolean {
    if (allowedRoles == null || allowedRoles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    const token = localStorage.getItem(
      authenticationSettings.authenticationToken
    );

    const status = this.jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(token);
    const decodeToken = this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken(token);
    if (!decodeToken) {
      console.log('Invalid token');
      return false;
    }
    decodeToken.roles = decodeToken.roles || [];
    const allow = allowedRoles.some(r => decodeToken.roles.includes(r));
    return allow;
  }

  get profileInfo(): User {
    return this.adal.userInfo;
  }

  get expirationDate() {
    const expiration = this.profileInfo.profile.exp * 1000;
    return moment(expiration);
  }

  get issueDate() {
    const expiration = this.profileInfo.profile.iat * 1000;
    return moment(expiration);
  }

  get hasExpired(): boolean {
    const today = moment();
    return this.expirationDate.isSameOrBefore(today);
  }

  get shouldRenew(): boolean {
    const today = moment().subtract(5, 'minutes');
    return this.expirationDate.isSameOrBefore(today);
  }

  get isAuthenticated() {
    const authenticated = this.adal.isAuthenticated;
    return authenticated;
  }

  updateSession() {
    if (this.hasExpired) {
      this.adal.login();
    } else if (this.shouldRenew) {
      this.adal.RenewToken(environment.ApiBaseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, we don't recommend trying to renew the token yourself, as you should let the library handle that as needed. Our recommendation for acquiring tokens is as follows:

1. Check if the user has signed in, and if not, send them to the login screen: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js#2-login-the-user
2. When your app is in the process of making a network request to a resource (e.g. Microsoft Graph) that requires an access token, call `acquireToken` with the scopes needed for that request.
3. If there is already a valid token in the cache, that token should be returned to you.
4. If there is not a valid token in the cache (e.g. an expired token) and your user still has an active session with AAD, the library will make a network request to acquire a new token, and return that new token to you.
5. If there is not a valid token in the cache, and your user does not have an active session with AAD or there is some other scenario that requires interaction (e.g. consenting to new scopes), the library will return an error and you will need to invoke one of the interactive methods (`acquireTokenPopup` or `acquireTokenRedirect`) to resolve those issues, and then the new token will be returned to your application: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js#3-get-an-access-token

Automatically trying to renew the token yourself may cause other issues, which is why we don't recommend it. Instead, call `acquireToken` lazily right before you need to the token, and then have error handling in place (as described above) to invoke interactive methods if needed.

Have you tried the process described above, and if so, what were the specific issues/errors that you encountered? Are there errors in the browser console or the network tab?